# Not able to trigger jobs one after the other using gcs-resource in concourse

Tags: concourse

I have two jobs viz. `build` and `publish`. I want `publish` to trigger after `build` is done. So, I am using an external resource  `gcs-resource`https://github.com/frodenas/gcs-resource

Following is my `pipeline.yml`:

```
---
resource_types:
  - name: gcs-resource
    type: docker-image
    source:
      repository: frodenas/gcs-resource

resources:
- name: proj-repo
  type: git
  source:
    uri: <my uri>
    branch: develop
    username: <username>
    password: <password>

- name: proj-gcr
  type: docker-image
  source:
      repository: asia.gcr.io/myproject/proj
      tag: develop
      username: _json_key
      password: <my password>

- name: proj-build-output
  type: gcs-resource
  source:
      bucket: proj-build-deploy
      json_key: <my key>
      regexp: Dockerfile

jobs:
- name: build
  serial_groups: [proj-build-deploy]
  plan:
  - get: proj
    resource: proj-repo
  - task: build
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: node, tag: 10.13.0}
      inputs:
      - name: proj
      run:
        path: sh
        args:
        - -exc
        - |
            <do something>

  - put: proj-build-output
    params:
        file: proj/Dockerfile
        content_type: application/octet-stream   

- name: publish
  serial_groups: [proj-build-deploy]
  plan:
  - get: proj-build-output
    trigger: true
    passed: [build]  

  - put: proj-gcr
    params:
      build: proj-build-output
```

I am using the external resource `proj-build-output` to trigger the next job. I can run the individual jobs without any problem, however the the `publish` job doesn't automatically get triggered after completion of `build` job.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Marco mentioned, the problem was with versioning. 
I solved my issue using these two steps:

1. Enabled versioning on my GCS Bucket https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning#_Enabling
2. Replaces `regexp` with `versioned_file` as mentioned in the docs https://github.com/frodenas/gcs-resource#file-names

Comment: I was asking to accept my answer, not yours, which is a copy of mine. Do you understand the spirit of stackoverflow? I spend my time and knowledge to answer your question, you in exchange accept my answer. You can even upvote it. Thank you.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. I accepted my answer because it is a more direct and precise answer to the original question. I will wait for the community for their comments.

Answer (score 1):

The `regexp` of the `gcs-resource` is misconfigured:

```
...
regexp: Dockerfile
...
```

while `regexp`, as the original S3 resource from which it comes from, wants:

> `regexp`: the pattern to match filenames against within GCS. The first grouped match is used to extract the version, or if a group is explicitly named version, that group is used.

The https://github.com/frodenas/gcs-resource#example-configuration shows its correct usage:

```
regexp: directory_on_gcs/release-(.*).tgz
```

This is not specific to the GCS or S3 resource; Concourse needs a "version" to move artifacts from jobs to storage and back. It is one of the fundamental concepts of Concourse. See https://web.archive.org/web/20171205105324/http://concourse.ci:80/versioned-s3-artifacts.html for an example.